# Проблема конфигурации Postfix (sendmail)

Tags: postfix, freebsd, sendmail

Сообщения вот такие в мэйллоге вижу я:

```
Feb 22 16:47:00 mail sendmail[37226]: r1MCl0oc037226: from=root, size=305, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201302221247.r1MCl0oc037226@mail.rogaikopyta.ru>, relay=root@localhostFeb 22 16:47:00 mail sm-mta[37227]: r1MCl00e037227: from=<root@mail.rogaikopyta.ru>, size=594, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201302221247.r1MCl0oc037226@mail.rogaikopyta.ru>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=Daemon0, relay=localhost.localdomain.ru [127.0.0.1]Feb 22 16:47:00 mail sendmail[37226]: r1MCl0oc037226: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30305, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (r1MCl00e037227 Message accepted for deliverFeb 22 16:47:00 mail sm-mta[37228]: r1MCl00e037227: SYSERR(root): MX list for rogaikopyta.ru. points back to mail.rogaikopyta.ruFeb 22 16:47:00 mail sm-mta[37228]: r1MCl00e037227: to=warn@rogaikopyta.ru, ctladdr=<root@mail.rogaikopyta.ru> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30863, relay=rogaikopyta.ru., dsn=5.3.5, stat=Local configuration errorFeb 22 16:47:00 mail sm-mta[37228]: r1MCl00e037227: r1MCl00e037228: DSN: Local configuration errorFeb 22 16:47:00 mail sm-mta[37228]: r1MCl00e037228: to=warn@rogaikopyta.ru, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=31887, relay=rogaikopyta.ru., dsn=5.3.5, stat=Local configuration errorFeb 22 16:47:00 mail sm-mta[37228]: r1MCl00e037228: r1MCl00f037228: return to sender: Local configuration errorFeb 22 16:47:00 mail sm-mta[37228]: r1MCl00f037228: to=warn@rogaikopyta.ru, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=32911, relay=rogaikopyta.ru., dsn=5.3.5, stat=Local configuration errorFeb 22 16:47:00 mail sm-mta[37228]: r1MCl00e037228: Losing ./qfr1MCl00e037228: savemail panicFeb 22 16:47:00 mail sm-mta[37228]: r1MCl00e037228: SYSERR(root): savemail: cannot save rejected email anywhere
```

Система freebsd 9.1 postfix 2.10

Где-то что-то забыл прописать я походу.На светлую сторону путь укажите мне...

Да прибудут с вами сила и знания.

Answer (score 2):

Наверное MX в DNS-сервере как минимум забыл прописать ты:

```
# nslookup -type=mx rogaikopyta.rurogaikopyta.ru  mail exchanger = 10 dial-148-240-4-32.zone-1.ip.dial.net.mx.rogaikopyta.ru  mail exchanger = 100 dial-148-240-4-32.zone-1.ip.dial.net.mx.
```

а быть mail.rogaikopyta.ru должен ведь

Comment: не, адрес MX нормальный, rogaikopyta.ru только для примера указал

Comment: тогда скажи реальный, никто ж не будет ломать